# I'm struggling with making search function with multi condition using django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
def influencer_board(request):
    user_input = []
    index_list = []
    influencer = Influencer_DB.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        sns_type = request.GET.get('sns_type') #0
        follower_num_min = request.GET.get('follower_num_min') #1
        follower_num_max = request.GET.get('follower_num_max') #2
        name = request.GET.get('name')#3
        gender = request.GET.get('gender')#4
        sns_id = request.GET.get('sns_id')#5
        keyword = request.GET.get('keyword')#6

        user_input.append(sns_type)
        user_input.append(follower_num_min)
        user_input.append(follower_num_max)
        user_input.append(name)
        user_input.append(gender)
        user_input.append(sns_id)
        user_input.append(keyword)

        for col in user_input:
            if col != "":
                index = user_input.index(col)
                index_list.append(index)

        influencer = Influencer_DB.objects
        for index in index_list:
            if index == 0:
                influencer = influencer.filter(sns_type=sns_type)
            if index == 1:
                influencer = influencer.filter(follower_num__gte = follower_num_min)
            if index == 2:
                influencer = influencer.filter(follower_num__lte = follower_num_max)
            if index == 3:
                influencer = influencer.filter(name=name)
            if index == 4:
                influencer = influencer.filter(gender = gender)
            if index == 5:
                influencer = influencer.filter(sns_id=sns_id)
            if index == 6:
                influencer = influencer.filter(keyword__icontains = keyword)

        return render(request,"influencer_board.html",{'influencer':influencer,"sns_type":sns_type,'follower_num_max':follower_num_max, 'followever':follower_num_min,'name':name, 'gender':gender,'sns_id':sns_id,'keyword':keyword})
    return render(request,"influencer_board.html",{'influencer':influencer})
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from main.views import main, go_back_and_clean,create_contract,show_record,confirm,delete,wait,delete_contract,celly_btn_info,btn_push,btn_create,btn_delete
from main.views import btn_condition_change
from login.views import login,logout,signup
from influencer_db.views import influencer_board

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/',main,name='home'),
    path('delete/', go_back_and_clean, name="delete"),
    path('',login, name='login'),
    path('logout/',logout, name='logout'),
    path('sign_up/',signup, name='signup'),
    path('create_contract/',create_contract,name='create_contract'),
    path('contract_board/<int:contract_id>',show_record,name='contract_board'),
    path('confirm/<int:record_id><int:contract_id>',confirm,name='confirm'),
    path('delete/<int:record_id><int:contract_id>',delete,name='delete'),
    path('wait/<int:record_id><int:contract_id>',wait,name='wait'),
    path('delete_contract/<int:contract_id>',delete_contract,name='delete_contract'),
    path('btn_info/<int:btn_id>',celly_btn_info,name='btn_info'),
    path('btn_push/<int:btn_id>',btn_push, name="btn_push"),
    path('btn_create/',btn_create,name='btn_create'),
    path('btn_delete/<int:btn_id>', btn_delete, name='btn_delete'),
    path('btn_condition_change/<int:btn_id>', btn_condition_change, name='btn_condtion_change'),
    path('influencer_board/',influencer_board,name="internal_influencer"),
```

Like the code above, I get 7 search condition from user. Also if user inputs less than 7 conditions, still I want to filter Database with those conditions. However, it keep making this error:

[image]

the function seems to work properly because the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/influencer_board/GET?
  sns_type=%EC%9D%B8%EC%8A%A4%ED%83%80%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8&follower_num_min=18000
  &follower_num_max=&name=&gender=&sns_id=&keyword=
```

contains the conditions what I submitted but making 404 error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show your urls.py

Comment: The URL `/influencer_board/GET` does not exist in your URL conf, and the view you showed does not redirect to that URL either. So where is this request comming from? Can you show the template that submits this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view code can be reduced and simplified. All 7 fields have similar filtering logic, so we can build a list of fields to filter (including their field filter like `__icontains` and `__gte`) and iterate over that list instead of writing almost the same thing 7 times.

Here is a suggestion that should have the same functionality with less code.

```
FILTER_KEYS = (
    ('sns_type', 'sns_type'),
    ('follower_num_min', 'follower_num__gte'),
    ('follower_num_max', 'follower_num__lte'),
    ('name', 'name'),
    ('gender', 'gender'),
    ('sns_id', 'sns_id'),
    ('keyword', 'keyword__icontains'),
)

def influencer_board(request):
    qs = Influencer_DB.objects.all()
    ctx = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        for key, field_with_filter in FILTER_KEYS:
            v = request.GET.get(key, '').strip()
            if len(v) == 0:
                # it's empty, so skip this
                continue

            # filter the QuerySet
            qs = qs.filter(**{field_with_filter: v})

            # add to context for template rendering
            ctx[key] = v

    # add to context for template rendering
    ctx['influencer'] = qs

    return render(request, "influencer_board.html", ctx)
```